# Загрузка данных в ExpandableListView

Tags: expandablelistview, android

как сделать что бы при переходе на другую активити и потом назад данные не загружались из интернета
мой адаптер:

```
public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private List<Category> catList;
private int itemLayoutId;
private int groupLayoutId;
private Context ctx;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView team1;
    public TextView team2;
    public TextView score;
    public TextView time;
    public ImageView imgTeam1;
    public ImageView imgTeam2;
    public TextView groupName;
  }

public ExpandableAdapter(List<Category> catList, Context ctx) {

    this.itemLayoutId = R.layout.child_view;
    this.groupLayoutId = R.layout.group_view;
    this.catList = catList;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return catList.get(groupPosition).getItemList().get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return catList.get(groupPosition).getItemList().get(childPosition).hashCode();
}
ViewHolder viewHolder;
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      
    View v = convertView;       
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.team1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team1);
    viewHolder.team2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team2);
    viewHolder.score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.score);
    viewHolder.time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
    viewHolder.imgTeam1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.team1Img);
    viewHolder.imgTeam2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.team2Img);        
      v.setTag(viewHolder);}
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
    ItemDetail det = catList.get(groupPosition).getItemList().get(childPosition);
    viewHolder.team1.setText(det.getTeam1());
    viewHolder.team2.setText(det.getTeam2());
    viewHolder.score.setText(det.getScore());
    viewHolder.time.setText(det.getTime());
    viewHolder.imgTeam1.setImageResource(det.getImgTeam1());
    viewHolder.imgTeam2.setImageResource(det.getImgTeam2());                
    return v;       
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    int size = catList.get(groupPosition).getItemList().size();
    System.out.println("Child for group ["+groupPosition+"] is ["+size+"]");
    return size;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return catList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
  return catList.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return catList.get(groupPosition).hashCode();
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.groupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.groupName);   
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    Category cat = catList.get(groupPosition);
    viewHolder.groupName.setText(cat.getName());
    return v;

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

 }
```

здесь заполняю адаптер:

```
 public void ListDrwaer() {          
    // упаковываем данные в понятную для адаптера структуру
  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   for (int j=0; j<8; j++){
       String[] groupName = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"};
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(groupName[j]);
   if (jsonMainNode.length() == 0){ continue;}
   else {
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    team1 = jsonChildNode.optString("team1");
    team2 = jsonChildNode.optString("team2");
    score = jsonChildNode.optString("score");
    time = jsonChildNode.optString("time0_90");
    group = jsonChildNode.optString("group");
    item = new ItemDetail(2, 0, team1, team2, score, time+"'", R.drawable.iran,  2130837509);
    result.add(item);
   }
   cat = createCategory("Группа " + group, j);   
   cat.setItemList(result); 
   catList.add(cat);
   result = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();
   }}
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }       
  ExpandableAdapter exAdpt = new ExpandableAdapter(catList, getActivity());
  exList.setAdapter(exAdpt);
  for(int i=0; i < exAdpt.getGroupCount(); i++)
      exList.expandGroup(i);
  catList = new ArrayList<Category>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кэшируйте данные в базу, а из нее уже заполняете ExpandableListView

---

[не самый лучший пример работы с бд но зато на русском](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html)
создаете бд нужной Вам структуры, и то что получили из сети записываете туда, ньюансы зависят конечно от приложения и данных - как за часто они меяеются и как ...  ну а адаптор заполнять соответственно из базы

Comment: если не трудно, напишите как это сделать